# does calculating the arithmetic mean of a serie of standar deviation measures make sense?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, means, hash-function

I'm trying to test if a hash function mantains a even distribution of values. My plan is to generate a set **X** of hashes and a integer **Y** symbolizing "slots" to see how many of the hashes maps to the slots given the mapping function **x mod Y** for every **x** in **X**. This is similar as how a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure works.

If every slot has a number **y** of mapped hashes, then I plan to calculate the standard deviation of these values respecting the expected value **count(X) / Y**. If repeat this test **N** times, I will end with **N** standar deviation values. Can I calculate then an arithmetic (maybe geometric?) mean to obtain a final value of how "evenly" distributed these hash function can be?

Sorry for bad english and/or bad statistics xD

Answer (score 1):

Adding the variances of your measurements to get an average variance would make more sense, this is because if $A$ and $B$ are random variables then Var(A+B) = Var(A)+Var(B) but the same is not true for standard deviations StDev(A+B) ≠ StDev(A)+StDev(B).

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that rule. Now using the variance instead of stdev makes more sense indeed :D